# FFmpeg: Transcoding videos with different audio and video stream start times

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I am trying to transcode user generated videos which sometimes have different start times for the audio and video streams. So far all transcoded videos result in the audio and video being out of sync when start times for the audio/video streams have differing start times.

The start time differences are not always constant.

### User generated video example

When playing the user-generated video, the audio and video are in sync.

Here is the [sample file](https://stampless-content.s3.amazonaws.com/examples/input.mp4). This video was recorded in a Safari browser.

Running

```
ffprobe input.mp4 -show_entries stream=codec_type,start_time,duration -of compact
```

on an example user-generated video outputs:

```
ffprobe version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.1 (Alpine 10.2.1_pre1) 20201203
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --enable-avresample --enable-avfilter --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-postproc --enable-pic --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-libxcb --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libvidstab --disable-stripping --disable-static --disable-librtmp --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libopus --enable-vulkan --enable-libsoxr --enable-libaom --disable-debug
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : iso5
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomiso5hlsf
    creation_time   : 2021-06-30T05:18:17.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:16.51, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9700 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 9815 kb/s, 28.89 fps, 600 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-06-30T05:18:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 185 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-06-30T05:18:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
stream|codec_type=video|start_time=0.506667|duration=16.005000
stream|codec_type=audio|start_time=0.000000|duration=16.044989
```

The audio and video streams are of different durations, but notably, the video start time is about 0.5 seconds later than the audio start time.

### The transcode command

```
ffmpeg  -i input.mp4 \
        -c:v libx264 \
        -crf 23 \
        -profile:v main \
        -r 30 \
        -video_track_timescale 30 \
        -level 3.0 \
        -pix_fmt yuv420p \
        -c:a aac \
        -ac 2 \
        -af aresample=async=1000 \
        -ar 44100 \
        -sample_fmt fltp \
        -b:a 128k \
        -vsync 1 \
        -vf scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black \
        output.mp4
```

### Output

The resulting file plays with the audio delayed

Running `ffprobe` again on the output video produces:

```
ffprobe version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.1 (Alpine 10.2.1_pre1) 20201203
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --enable-avresample --enable-avfilter --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-postproc --enable-pic --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-libxcb --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libvidstab --disable-stripping --disable-static --disable-librtmp --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libopus --enable-vulkan --enable-libsoxr --enable-libaom --disable-debug
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:17.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5177 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 5241 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 102 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
stream|codec_type=video|start_time=0.000000|duration=16.500000
stream|codec_type=audio|start_time=0.000000|duration=17.045011
```

The durations of the video and audio streams are off by about 0.5 seconds and out of sync.

### Attempted Solutions

I have tried `-fflags +shortest` and several `-map` commands, as well as removing the `faststart` command to no avail.

One possible solution I'm trying to avoid is calculating the offset and padding the audio stream by a fixed time amount (~0.5seconds in this case).

Ideally a solution would be able to handle different start times. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a short sample input file?

Comment: Hi @llogan, I just added a link to the sample file used (https://stampless-content.s3.amazonaws.com/examples/input.mp4)